# python data frame filter conditions: any faster way

Tags: python, pandas, filter

```
parts_list = imp_parts_df['Parts'].tolist()
sub_week_list = ['2016-12-11', '2016-12-04', '2016-11-27', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-13'] 
i = 0
start = DT.datetime.now()
for p in parts_list:
       for thisdate in sub_week_list:
            thisweek_start = pd.to_datetime(thisdate, format='%Y-%m-%d') #'2016/12/11'
            thisweek_end = thisweek_start + DT.timedelta(days=7)  # add 7 days to the week date

            val_shipped = len(shipment_df[(shipment_df['loc'] == 'USW1') & (shipment_df['part'] == str(p)) & (shipment_df['shipped_date'] >= thisweek_start) & (shipment_df['shipped_date'] < thisweek_end)])

print(DT.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
```

`shipment_df` has around 35000 records

`partlist` has 436 parts

`sub_week_list` has 5 dates in it

it took overall **438.13** secs to run this code

Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: Faster way to do what?  You assigned an integer to the same variable 436 times.

Comment: please see the edited version.....my question is why is it taking so much time for filter condition to run.... normally the loop is running fine but when i put this filter criteria on dataframe ...its taking time...is there a way of filtering faster

Comment: you can actually do away with the loop and that will speed things up.

Comment: For improvement purposes please use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
parts_list = imp_parts_df['Parts'].astype(str).tolist()
i = 0
start = DT.datetime.now()
for p in parts_list:

    q = 'loc == "xxx" & part == @p & "2016-11-20" <= shipped_date < "2016-11-27"'
    val_shipped = len(shipment_df.query(q))

print (DT.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ..i used your 'query' filtering approach to my code ..it took **230.078** secs ...which was good. but still donot you think its more considering the simple code